# Inner product of basis polynomial and its derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a basis for the polynomials with degree at most $n-1$. We define the inner product $\langle p, q\rangle := \int\limits_0^{1} p(t)q(t)w(t)$, for a continous function $w$.

Is it true that $\langle p_k,p'_k\rangle = 0, \forall 0 \leq k \leq n$, for arbitrary choice of normalized (i.e. $ \| p_k\|= \sqrt{\langle  p_k,p_k \rangle} 
 = 1$) basis polynomials? If so, does this still hold for any orthogonal set?

If one or both are true, how could one proof that?

Comment: What about $w\equiv 1$ and $p_1(x)=x$ ?

Comment: This turned out easier than expected, thanks.
I think I read something like that but I can't find it any more. Does it maybe work for normalized polynomials?

Comment: For the particular case of $w=1$, the condition $\langle p, p'\rangle=0$ is equivalent to $p(0)^2=p(1)^2$, since $\langle p, p'\rangle = \int p p' dt = \frac{1}{2} \int (p^2)' dt = \frac{1}{2}(p(1)^2 - p(0)^2)$.

Comment: I noticed that already but $w \neq 1$ is what makes this tough.

Comment: @VinzenzLichtenwallner There are many examples too for $w=x$ for instance. (Take the same polynomial as above.)